# Populating multiple text fields in vb.net from a text file

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, flat-file

I am attempting to populate 5 boxes on a form from a text file using VB.net.  The text file is a report sent to me that contains an unknown number of lines as the events of each day are different. In the text file, each line contains 5 items separated by a "~".

ie:
AccountNumber~Name~Phone~email~data

The form I have setup is just a simple form with 5 text boxes and 2 buttons.  (In addition to the file menu to open the txt file).

The 2 buttons are for a "Previous record" and "Next Record" feature.  They would do the obvious.

Here is the code I have so far.  It's all in the File > Open menu item (which may in itself be wrong) so I'm including that whole setup.

I have it to where it will pop a message box for each item in each line one at a time.  Also, it keeps track by counting from 0 to 4 so I know when it's back at the first item.  In testing, that works.

I need to figure out how to get all 5 items from the first line to show in the text boxes and then, make the "Next" and "Previous" buttons go to the next or previous line and populate the text boxes from those.  Each process I've tried has failed miserably.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

```
Private Sub OpenToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OpenToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim ofd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog
    ofd.DefaultExt = "txt"
    ofd.FileName = "defaultname"
    ofd.InitialDirectory = "C:\users\%username%\desktop\"
    ofd.Filter = "Text files|*.txt"
    ofd.Title = "Select file"

    If ofd.ShowDialog() <> DialogResult.Cancel Then
        Using myreader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(ofd.FileName)
            myreader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
            myreader.SetDelimiters("~")

            Dim currentrow As String()
            While Not myreader.EndOfData
                Try
                    currentrow = myreader.ReadFields()
                    Dim currentfield As String
                    For Each currentfield In currentrow
                        Dim count As Integer

                        If count = 4 Then
                            count = 0

                        Else
                            ' populate form

                            MsgBox(currentfield & " - " & count)
                            count = count + 1


                        End If

                    Next
                Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.
                    fileio.MalformedLineException
                    MsgBox("line " & ex.Message &
            "is not valid and will be skipped.")
                End Try
            End While

        End Using

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Can the data item ever contain a "~"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store all the string arrays for each line in a structure OUTSIDE of the import method so that you can move forward and/or backwards through them.

Here I've stored them in a `List(Of String())`:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private _dataIndex As Integer = -1
    Public Property DataIndex As Integer
        Get
            Return _dataIndex
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            If value >= 0 AndAlso value < data.Count Then
                _dataIndex = value
                UpdateCurrentRecord()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Private TextBoxes() As TextBox
    Private data As New List(Of String())

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' ...change the names of the textboxes below...
        TextBoxes = {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4, TextBox5}
    End Sub

    Private Sub OpenToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OpenToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Dim ofd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog
        ofd.DefaultExt = "txt"
        ofd.FileName = "defaultname"
        ofd.InitialDirectory = "C:\users\%username%\desktop\"
        ofd.Filter = "Text files|*.txt"
        ofd.Title = "Select file"

        If ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            _dataIndex = -1
            data.Clear()
            UpdateCurrentRecord()

            Using myreader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(ofd.FileName)
                myreader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
                myreader.SetDelimiters("~")

                Dim currentrow As String()
                While Not myreader.EndOfData
                    Try
                        currentrow = myreader.ReadFields()
                        If currentrow.Length = 5 Then
                            data.Add(currentrow)
                        End If
                    Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                        MessageBox.Show("Line " & ex.Message & " is not valid and will be skipped.")
                    End Try
                End While

                If data.Count > 0 Then
                    DataIndex = 0
                End If
            End Using
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdateCurrentRecord()
        If _dataIndex >= 0 AndAlso _dataIndex < data.Count Then
            Dim row() As String = data(_dataIndex)
            If row.Length = 5 Then
                For i As Integer = 0 To 4
                    TextBoxes(i).Text = row(i)
                Next
            End If
        Else
            For Each tb As TextBox In TextBoxes
                tb.Clear()
            Next
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnPrev_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrev.Click
        DataIndex = (DataIndex - 1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
        DataIndex = (DataIndex + 1)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you.  Now to work on adding the ability to search using any of the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this instead in your code to get the correct fields ! !

```
If ofd.ShowDialog() <> DialogResult.Cancel Then
        Using myreader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(ofd.FileName)
            myreader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
            myreader.SetDelimiters("~")
            Dim x As Short
            Dim currentrow As String()
            While Not myreader.EndOfData
                Try
                    currentrow = myreader.ReadFields()
                    Dim Count As Short = 0
                    For x = 0 To currentrow.Count - 1
                        Count = Count + 1

                        MsgBox(currentrow(x) & " - " & Count)

                       
                    Next
                Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.
                FileIO.MalformedLineException
                    MsgBox("line " & ex.Message &
        "is not valid and will be skipped.")
                End Try
            End While

        End Using
End If
```

You can also do this:-

You can also use the logic I have shown above but first get all lines into a array -  then manipulate each line :-

```
Dim Lines = File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName)
        Dim Lp As Single
        Dim X As Short
        For Lp = 0 To Lines.Length - 1
            Dim items() As String = Split(Lines(Lp), "~")
            Dim Count As Short = 0
            For x = 0 To items.Count - 1
                Count = Count + 1
                MsgBox(items(X) & " - " & Count)
            Next
        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me.

```
Private curIndex As Integer = -1
Private maxIndex As Integer = 0
Private dic As Dictionary(Of Integer, String()) = New Dictionary(Of Integer, String())
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Where(Function(x) Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
    maxIndex = lines.Count - 1
    For i As Integer = 0 To maxIndex
        dic.Add(i, lines(i).Split("~"c).Where(Function(x) Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToArray())
    Next
    Label1.Text = "0"
    curIndex = 0
    TextBox1.Text = dic(0)(curIndex)
    TextBox2.Text = dic(0)(curIndex + 1)
    TextBox3.Text = dic(0)(curIndex + 2)
    TextBox4.Text = dic(0)(curIndex + 3)
    TextBox5.Text = dic(0)(curIndex + 4)
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Not curIndex - 1 < 0 Then
        curIndex -= 1
        Label1.Text = curIndex.ToString
        TextBox1.Text = dic(curIndex)(0)
        TextBox2.Text = dic(curIndex)(1)
        TextBox3.Text = dic(curIndex)(2)
        TextBox4.Text = dic(curIndex)(3)
        TextBox5.Text = dic(curIndex)(4)
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If Not curIndex + 1 > maxIndex Then
        curIndex += 1
        Label1.Text = curIndex.ToString
        TextBox1.Text = dic(curIndex)(0)
        TextBox2.Text = dic(curIndex)(1)
        TextBox3.Text = dic(curIndex)(2)
        TextBox4.Text = dic(curIndex)(3)
        TextBox5.Text = dic(curIndex)(4)
    End If
End Sub
```

You can use Dictionary to save line number and values.